# Unable to access keychain from Unwanted Communication Extension iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios12

I am creating Unwanted Communication Extension extension for my app, But when i try to access the keychain for login details, it is not able to access the keychain.

Note: Entitlements with keychain sharing is added and keychain sharing is on for my app.

I tried using this code on my extension view controller and it returns error code `-25291` on `SecItemCopyMatching`

```
let queryLoad: [String: AnyObject] = [
  kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
  kSecAttrAccount as String: itemKey as AnyObject,
  kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
  kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
  kSecAttrAccessGroup as String: keychainAccessGroupName as AnyObject
]

var result: AnyObject?

let resultCodeLoad = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) {
  SecItemCopyMatching(queryLoad as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
}

if resultCodeLoad == noErr {
  if let result = result as? Data,
    let keyValue = NSString(data: result,
                            encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as? String {

    // Found successfully
    print(keyValue)
  }
} else {
  print("Error loading from Keychain: \(resultCodeLoad)")
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code and any error messages you are getting